# How to combine two query to improve performance

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The system that I'm currently working on is a legacy system. The result of the first query have no issue just that the query will go through a loop to retrieve another value using the result from the first query. I try to change the query from "order by id" to "order by date" since I'm having some issue for certain account if the table is order by id. I also tried to change the query because it's currently very slow. I did combine both query together but it takes a long time to execute.
How do I join 2 query together without affecting the performance?

/* This query as I mention has no issue (first query)*/

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT('2016-12-12 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d') AS date,
C.id AS account_id,
C.account_no,
C.account_name,
B.amount AS last_topup,
DATE_FORMAT('2016-12-12 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d') AS topup_date,
NULL AS balance
FROM (SELECT
      account_id,
      MAX(date) date
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY account_id) A 
INNER JOIN table1 B
USING (account_id, date)
RIGHT JOIN table2 C ON B.account_id = C.id
ORDER BY C.account_no;
```

/* Loop query (second query)*/

```
SELECT
`t`.`balance_after` AS `balance`
FROM table3 `t`
WHERE `t`.`account_id` = '<id from the loop>' AND `t`.`date` <= '2017-07-26 
23:59:59'
ORDER BY `t`.`date` DESC;
```

/* The query that I combined both (takes a long time to execute*/

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT('2016-12-12 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d') AS date,
C.id AS account_id,
C.account_no,
C.account_name,
B.amount AS last_topup,
DATE_FORMAT('2016-12-12 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d') AS topup_date,
D.balance_after AS balance
FROM (SELECT
      account_id,
      MAX(date) date
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY account_id) A 
INNER JOIN table1 B
USING (account_id, date)
RIGHT JOIN table2 C ON B.account_id = C.id
RIGHT JOIN table3 D ON B.account_id = D.account_id
WHERE D.date <= "2017-07-30 23:59:59"
ORDER BY C.account_no;
```

Comment: Can you share the EXPLAIN plan? In the third query there is `AND `t`.`date` <= '2017-07-26 ` condition missing, that might affect the performance. Also check/share indexes - just adding few indexes may help you.

Comment: I edit the query but still taking long time to execute. The table already have index in it.